# wordpress config - Error establishing a database connection localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get away from using Mamp, so have recently installed mysql, edited my vhosts and am attempting to run an instance of wordpress from a url that's not localhost.

I think I'm doing something wrong with mysql, as wordpress can't seem to access my database.

I get this error from wordpress -

```
[2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in in /Users/myusername/workspaces/wordpress/test/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1017
```

my wordpress config looks like this -

```
define('DB_NAME', 'test_db');
define('DB_USER', 'test_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test_password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I'm accessing mysql from the terminal and am still finding my way around a recent move from windows, but I'm fairlry certain I've set up the user and db correctly.

A solution would be great, but would also appreciate some tips on how I go about debugging a problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir /var/mysql

ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Mac is not Unix. So try this.

And for the tip: when you see an error like `No such file or directory`, you're missing a file or directory that the script expect to find.
E.g. if my solution is not working find where mysql.sock is and make a link pointing to `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Apparently it's happening for [Mac OS X 10.4.4+](http://codex.wordpress.org/MacOS_X_Local_Mirror#Install_and_Configure_MySQL)

Comment: that's prefect thanks. Any idea why it thought it was unix to begin with?

Comment: I have edited the answer with the link. It thought it was unix because macos is a unix system.